# Indent a wrapped text

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap, styling

I currently have this text that is wrapped by using the following style

```
<pre style="font-family: inherit; white-space: break-spaces; word-break: break-all;></pre>
```

The problem is that the text in the `jws` property doesn't respect the indentation of the previous properties (`verificationMethod`)

[image]

Is there a way to start the next line from the red bar?

The text is simply

```
<pre style="font-family: inherit; white-space: break-spaces; word-break: break-all;>
...
"verificationMethod": "proof_verification_method",
"jws": "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"
        }
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Going to need more code than that. How is `jws` and `verificationMethod` html is structured and classed applied. This behaviour can happen from various reasons.

Comment: Can you add in a whole snippet with the pre and all the text as at the moment we can’t actually see why jws should be indented at all, and in particular it is doubtful that the indentation of the previous ‘properly’, which is in fact just text, has anything to do with the positioning of jws.

Comment: the `jws` property is a very long text

Comment: There is no indentation concept in the `pre`. The indentation you see is present in your text before you insert it in the `pre` element. Looks like formatted JSON and the spaces are already in it.

Comment: so there is no way to do that, am I right?

Comment: 'no way' is quite strong - it depends on what your constraints are. As others have said, pre is just giving you whatever spacing there is in the text. If  you want formatting beyond that you'd have to add some structure to the text, like introduce elements and style them but given what you have shown us looks like code of some sort you probably don't want to do that (particurly if the user is likely to copy and paste the text). I appreciate the string is long, but could you clarify whether in the original it is just one long line or not?

Comment: Please could you show us the code? (you can shorten the long string if it's really too much). Something must be styling the bold for example, but can we see it please?

Comment: I cannot provide the full code, it is just a json stringified object that contains a `jws` property that contains a long text.